# Graficar tabla sqlserver con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo una tabla creada en una BD sql server la cual contiene 4 columnas fecha, x, y, z,
quiero graficarla con matplotlib pero no lo e logrado, les dejo lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
import pyodbc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=localhost;'
                      'Database=prueba;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dbo.tabla_prueba')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Intentaste graficar la consulta de alguna forma y te arrojo algún error? , podrías mostrar un poco más los datos que manejas ?

Comment: Por otro lado te puedo aconsejar utilizar `pandas` para leer la query, y puedes hacerlo de esta manera : `df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM dbo.tabla_prueba',conn)` y si te sirve puedes usar  `df['columna'].hist()`